# Quality standards seem to be a bit high these days

Tags: support

My question was:

```
"Remove unnecessary step" phrase synonym

What is another way of saying "remove unnecessary step"?
```

But the posting page doesn't let it through. Is the question really bad and doesn't meet certain quality standards, or it contains no-no words?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, it doesn't contain any contextual information. When you write a phrase request, you must include the context you wish to use the synonym in, and indicate what phrases you have looked for in a thesaurus, for instance, and why they are not suitable for your purposes.

This helps the answerer give you what you need without guessing, and also makes it less likely that your question will be closed.

Comment: I tried looking in online dictionaries, but the initial phrasing is not very good to find relevant results. Should I include such facts in my question?

Comment: @user Absolutely.

Answer (score 3):

First, to get it out of the way, there are no words that are completely prohibited on Stack Exchange, and the only restriction is that profanity may be used only when discussing the profanity in question.

The "quality standards" are an automatic filter; I would highly suggest you give some additional background in your question, which should more than overcome the filter. For example, why are you looking for this phrase? That helps give answerers context so that they know whether or not a particular answer would be appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

The only thing wrong with your question was that it contained insufficient context.

Without knowing the overall context of where and how the phrase would be used, it's almost impossible to answer the question. For example, I might suggest *amputate unneeded step* – I doubt that would be a good alternative, but, without any additional information, it's hard to say for sure.

Moreover, to a carpenter, a *step* is part of a staircase; to a dancer, it's part of a routine; to a cook, it's part of a recipe; to a pedestrian, it's part of a journey. What kind of step are we removing?

It would also help if you shared some information about your target audience. Who are we addressing?  MBA students? Software engineers? Kindergartners?  One important factor in figuring out a good way to rephrase something is knowing *who* will be reading the reworded text.

If you provide such information – to include what you don't like about the current wording – I think you'll get more help.  Without that information, though, this isn't about "quality standards" as much as it is about asking questions that are answerable.

That all said, this site does strive for high standards, so it wouldn't hurt to keep that in mind.